# MySQL process explanation

Tags: linux, mysql

I have one **MySQL** process on my server running linux and it's always running it takes at least 50% usage of 1 Core (I have 8 cores)...
This is process command:

```
/usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/ --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql --log-error=/var/lib/mysql/server.mydomain.com.err --pid-file=/var/lib/mysql/server.mydomain.com.pid
```

What this process is doing?
This is not the issue just a question.

Comment: I want to reduce my CPU usage as far I can, that is the reason why I am asking this :)

Comment: You need to narrow the scope of what you're asking substantially. If you have a problem, state it, along with any error messages you have received, research you've done, and steps you've taken to remedy the problem which haven't worked.  See [this meta question](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3608/how-can-i-ask-better-questions-on-server-fault) for more help on formulating a good, answerable question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check what the mysql daemon is actually working on internally. Mysql has a list of internal processes, try running the following:

```
mysql -u root -p -e "SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST"
```

if you have your password in your ~/.my.cnf you can use watch to keep an eye on your mysql processlist in a faux top format:

```
watch -n 1 mysql -u root -e \"SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST\"
```

If mysql is constantly doing 50%, then its probably working on something, if you can see the queries then there might be a way of optimizing it.

Answer (score 2):

mytop - a command line utility for monitoring the threads and performances of MySQL performance. Using this you can able to find out which process is eating up your resources and you can optimize according to that.

Another way to optimize your mysql is **mysqltuner** script - its just a small perl script, when you run this on your machine, it will provide a recommended values to optimize your mysql server with your current resource setup.....

Comment: Thank you for notifying me about **mysqltuner** script :)
I did optimization by recommendations from the script and this process is taking 50% less usage.